# gdata xml parsing with dom

Tags: java, xml, parsing, gdata

I'm looking for a way to get the keywords from youtube video gdata.

The xml Looks something like the following:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:media='http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/' xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005' xmlns:yt='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007'>
<id>http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/vidid</id>
<category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat' term='Comedy' label='Comedy'/>

<category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat' term='kw1'/>
<category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat' term='kw2'/>
<category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat' term='kw3'/>
<category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat' term='kw4'/>
<category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat' term='kw5'/>

<title type='text'>vid title</title>
...
</entry>
```

I cut some stuff out where the ... is, so I can get the title using the following code:

```
public static String getTitle(String id) throws IOException, ParserConfigurationException, XPathExpressionException, SAXException {


    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.parse("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/" + id);

    XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();
    XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//entry/title/text()");

    Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.STRING);
    String title = (String) result;
    return title;
}
```

Is there some way to modify this to get the keywords too? 
I should mention, there can be any number of keywords, not just 5 as shown above.

Comment: Try this xpath `//entry/category/@term` it will give you all keywords in this fashion `'kw1', 'kw2', 'kw3', 'kw4', 'kw5'`.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I initially tried doing it like that except i have two problems with it. Firstly, it returns the category type term and secondly I dont actually know how to make it return each of the keywords. Currently it just returns the first.

Comment: To get just the keywork catagory, try `//entry/category[contains(@scheme,'keywords.cat')]/@term`. If you're having issues with namespaces, try: `//*[local-name()='entry']/*[local-name()='category'][contains(@scheme,'keywords.cat')]/@term `

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for replies people. I have hacked something out myself that seems to do the trick

```
   public static ArrayList getTags(String id) throws IOException, ParserConfigurationException, XPathExpressionException, SAXException {
    ArrayList<String> tags = new ArrayList<String>();

    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.parse("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/" + id);
    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("category");

    for (int i = 0; i<nl.getLength(); i++) {
        String kwCheck = "http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat";
        if (kwCheck.equals(nl.item(i).getAttributes().getNamedItem("scheme").getNodeValue()) ) {
            String kw = nl.item(i).getAttributes().getNamedItem("term").getNodeValue();       
            tags.add(kw);
        }
    }

    return tags;
}
```

This returns keywords only but could probably do with some tidying up. Any of you see any issues with this method ? Thanks again